# How to create hybrid certificates using bouncy castle

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle, x509

Is there a way to create a hybrid certificate in the current bouncy castle version? I checked the wiki and coudn't find any X.509 extension supporting this. Did I miss the extension (for example https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-truskovsky-lamps-pq-hybrid-x509-00.html) in the wiki or is there no support implemented? If there is no support, do I have to implement a custom version or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to create certificate with alternative public keys based on specified RFC draft. Even manually. One blocking limitation is the absence of valid object identifiers for proposed extensions, they all have status TBD (to be determined).

Even after RFC release there will be little sense to create such certificates as long as there are no applications that will support new extensions and be able to process them accordingly.